# Is there a UIButtonCell like NSButtonCell in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

If I want to make a 10X10 buttons in a view, the simple way is to make 100 buttons,
in Cocoa there is a `NSButtonCell`can be used, so is there some thing like it in iOS?

Comment: `UIButton`?  What's the difference between `NSButton` and `NSButtonCell`?  What exactly are you trying to do?  If you want to make 10x10 buttons in a view, you can do it on the storyboard, or programmatically by making 100 `UIButton` objects.

Comment: @nhgrif NSButton can contain many NSButtonCells, every button-cell performs like a button, and all cells just in one NSButton,that means you need only one NSButton.

Comment: Hrm.  Sounds like `UIButton` is equivalent to `NSButtonCell` then.  I'm not sure there's anything quite like `NSButton` in `iOS`.  `UIButton` is the class you use to make a button in iOS.

Comment: `UITableView` is a container for `UITableViewCells`, which can be selected in the same way as buttons.  The same goes for `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewCells`.  But with these, you have limited control as to how/where buttons are placed, whereas a `UIButton` can be placed anywhere.

Comment: @nhgrif Yes I know that, I just think placing 100 UIButtons in a view is not that effective.

Comment: How would you do it for OSX?

Comment: What you're saying about NSButton is not true -- it only has one button cell. What you mean is an NSMatrix of button cells, and no there's nothing quite like that in iOS. A collection view can give you a grid of UIButtons, but the setup for a collection view is quite different -- it's not accessed by row and column like a matrix in OSX.

Answer (score 0):

your can create a custom cell

1. drag and drop a tableView cell and design with your buttons
   and

add your custom tableView cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath like this,

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
    static NSString *yourCustomeCelldentifier = @"CustomeTableCell";
    yourCustomeCell *cell = (yourCustomeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:yourCustomeCelldentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib;
        nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomeCell_Nib" owner:self options:nil];                   
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }              

    return cell;
```

}

hope this way will help you